# large area anchor tag not clicking to URL

Tags: css

The `a.panel-link` links to a URL. It contains a `<span>`.

Only the text inside the `<span>` is clickable, not the whole `a.panel-link` which is much larger than the text inside the `<span>`.

How do I make the whole `a.panel-link` clickable to the URL?

Help appreciated.

```css
.panel {
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: left;
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
}
.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.panel-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/kitchen-menu-scaled.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
  <a class="panel-link" href="https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/design-build/kitchen-renovations-brisbane/" title="Kitchens">
    <span class="panel-text">Kitchens</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: in example that you provided whole a is hidden under `.panel-bg` element becouse of `z-index`. After adding `z-index: -1;` to `.panel-bg` whole `a` element area is clickable

Comment: Thanks @ciekals11. If this question deserves to stay, add an answer, that fixed it.

Comment: @SRDMH I think you want to click on images and the page will redirect to another URL it's right ?

Answer (score 1):

move `position: absolute` from `span` element to `a` and move text to bottom left corner using for example flexbox.

And don't use `z-index: 9999;` use proper order to help debug later.
(it's easier to look at z-index 1,2,3,4 than 99999, 9999999, 99999999, 999999999

```css
.panel {
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: left;
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
}

.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.panel-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/kitchen-menu-scaled.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
    <a class="panel-link" href="https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/design-build/kitchen-renovations-brisbane/" title="Kitchens">
        <span class="panel-text">Kitchens</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

EDIT:
and the best approach will be to move `.panel-bg` into `.panel-link`
an omit one of `position: absolute`

notice that i had to add `position: relative; z-index: 1` to span element.
On default `absolute` is "higher" than `relative` is even on same `z-index` level

```css
.panel {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 320px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

.panel-link {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.panel-link span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <a class="panel-link" href="https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/design-build/kitchen-renovations-brisbane/" title="Kitchens">
        <span class="panel-text">Kitchens</span>
        <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/kitchen-menu-scaled.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Add some CSS please add in your Code Hope It's Help You

```
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute; // ADD THIS NEW LINE
    left: 0; // ADD THIS NEW LINE
    top: 0; // ADD THIS NEW LINE
}
.panel-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 40px; // ADD THIS NEW LINE
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` needs a `position` that is not `static`.

```css
.panel {
    height: 250px;
    background-size: contain;
    text-align: left;
    width: 320px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 40px;
}
.panel-bg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-link {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;  // ADD THIS NEW LINE Only
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.panel-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0),rgba(21, 21, 21, 0), rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.7)), url('https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/kitchen-menu-scaled.jpg')" class="panel-bg"></div>
  <a class="panel-link" href="https://www.allbathroomgear.com.au/design-build/kitchen-renovations-brisbane/" title="Kitchens">
    <span class="panel-text">Kitchens</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `z-index` requires setting the position type. Add the property `position:relative;` e.g. to `.panel-link`